# Where to find the laws regarding women's right to know before abortion in US?

Tags: united-states, abortion

What is known as ‘women’s right to know’ laws, are laws concerning the information that a woman must be exposed to if she is considering an abortion. These laws mandate, for example, that a woman must be told about at least one of the following: the (purported) link between abortion and breast cancer, the (purported) ability of a foetus to feel pain and the (purported) negative mental health consequences of abortion.

Where to find the details of these laws?
Are there corresponding laws in other countries?

Comment: Note that these would be *state* laws, not federal, so you may have to search state-by-state.  Many states don't have such laws at all, and in those that do, the details will vary.

Answer (score 2):

You could start with [this article](https://www.usnews.com/news/best-states/articles/a-guide-to-abortion-laws-by-state) , and find the last column "counseling required". This would tell you that North Carolina has such a law, then try googling "North Carolina Women's Right to Know Act, which will lead you to [the actual act](https://www.ncleg.gov/EnactedLegislation/Statutes/PDF/ByArticle/Chapter_90/Article_1I.pdf). I'm not aware of analogs in other countries, which generally just make abortion illegal if that's the goal.

Comment: I didn’t find anything about breast cancer in the act.

Comment: That suggests, if you were looking at the North Carolina act, that it doesn't specifically mandate anything about breast cancer. Check the law of the state that purportedly has that requirement.